# How to make content slowly 'fade out' when it nears the edge of an overflow:hidden div?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I hope I'm not confusing anyone. My div has a height of 300px, and the content is bigger than the div. I have set `overflow` to `hidden` inside the div, and all is going fine. It's just it would be better if when the user scrolls the content, anything above and under the bottom of the page won't just disappear right after a certain point, I want there to probably be a half-transparent image on the top and bottom of the div, so that when the user scrolls, the content slowly fades away and in.

As I have said, hope I'm not confusing anyone.

Comment: you just need a png gradient image with lil transparency at the top and you need to use fix position, `bottom:0px;` and its done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar to this before. Unfortunately, the code is not with me at the moment.

However, I did use this website as reference, perhaps it could help you:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/

Comment: That is a good start but make sure to leave enough space so that the last line of the text does not have the fading image over it. Makes the text hard to read.

Comment: Yes, just to clarify, as I had to read that comment twice to understand. What @sarcastyx means is that when you reach the end of the text in the div, that the last bit of text doesn't fall under that fading image. This can be achieved by adding a few linebreaks after the last line.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that point. After reading the comment again, yeah I found it confusing too. Also I would not add `br` tags and instead use `padding-bottom` to move the text up.

Comment: `padding-bottom` is a much better (and neater) way of doing that, yes.

Comment: You can avoid using an image by using the [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient) function with [rgba()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value#RGBa_(red-green-blue-alpha)_rgba(R.2CG.2CB.2Ca)_) colours, which would be easier to maintain. Unfortunately IE won't support `linear-gradient` until IE10, but it will fall back gracefully: it just won't show a fade in IE9 and earlier but will in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: @StuCox, good idea. If you wish to use the `linear-gradient`, pre-IE10 issues can be fixed by having a separate stylesheet for IE in the `<!--[if IE]-->` tags OR use filters.

Comment: @DarkRanger - yep, although shouldn't be necessary. Actually for IE6-9 you might be able to combine MS' proprietary [filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx) and [filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967(v=vs.85).aspx) properties to achieve the same effect - and other browsers would simply ignore them - but I haven't tried it myself!